# Error when test jquery dependenci on Laravel Mix or Encore webpack

Tags: jquery, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

In my project I use vuejs and not jquery. When testing jquery, the webpack encore returns an error. Below is an example js of the output code and error.

**My js:**

```
if (typeof jQuery! == "undefined" && typeof jQuery.fn! == "undefined") {
console.log ("jquery is in the project");
} From others {
console.log ("jquery is not in the project");
}
```

**Output error:**

> This dependency was not found:
>
> jquery

I don't really use jquery, so my console.log should generate "jquery is not in the project"

There is another way to test jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this, the problem was in webpack.config.js, I was using .autoProvidejQuery() but I don’t use jquery, so I commented this line